# Why does System.in.read() wait till the user presses enter?

Tags: java, console, system.in

> `System.in.read()` is used to read a **single character**.

Then why does it allow the user to enter as many characters as he can until he presses enter?

Why doesn't it stop as soon as he presses a key and returns the character?

```
char ch = (char)System.in.read();
```

If the user enter "example" and then press enter, It takes the `ch` as `e`. and discards the other characters.

If there are multiple `read()`, it messes the whole thing.

So, why doesn't it take only the single character and then return?

Comment: It is the *terminal* that is *line oriented*. It is the *terminal* that *only gives STDIN the line when enter is pressed*. Java itself does just what it promises to do - *once* it has the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307355/system-in-read-does-not-read

Comment: Useful information/links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it?rq=1

Comment: Yeah what that user said. To get single key action, you have to set the terminal in raw mode and interpret key codes directly.

Comment: perfectly what I needed. Please answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

`System.in` is of type [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html). This type of stream caches input data until newline character is recognized. The following snippet shows you the type in the output.

```
System.out.println(System.in.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

> If there are multiple read(), it messes the whole thing.
>   So, why doesn't it take only the single character and then return?

To solve this issue you can wrap the *standard input* and read it with a `Scanner` instead.

For the given input:

> abcd
>   1234

the following `Scanner` code will pick just the chars `a` and `1`.

```
// Local vars init
char ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0;

// Wrap the stdin with scanner
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

if(s.hasNextLine()) ch1 = s.nextLine().charAt(0); // reads "abcd", picks just 'a'
if(s.hasNextLine()) ch2 = s.nextLine().charAt(0); // reads "1234", picks just '1'

System.out.println(ch1 + "," + ch2); // prints a,1

// Close after use
s.close();
```

Comment: I know this, I just wanted to know why didn't read() stop after taking a single character.