# One of my Inputs is skipped

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I need to use BufferedReader, System.in.read() with a thrown exception and System.in.read() with catch and try.
This is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public void Bufferedreader() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader In = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String expr = new String();
        System.out.print("Input:  ");
        expr = In.readLine();
        System.out.println("Output: " + expr);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    }


    public void throwexception() throws IOException {
        int Eingabe=20;
        System.out.print("\nInput");
        Eingabe=System.in.read();
        System.out.println("\n" + (char)Eingabe);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    }

    public void Exception() {
        int i=32;
        System.out.print("\nEingabe ");

        try {
            i=System.in.read();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Eingabefehler "+ e);
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + (char)i);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Test method = new Test();
        method.Bufferedreader();
        method.Exception();
        method.throwexception();
    }
}
```

BufferedReader works fine and so does one of the System.in.read() Inputs but the third input is always skipped. Both System.in.read work separately but I cannot get both System.in.read() to work together.

Here's what the output looks like:

```
Input:  5

Output: 5

------------------------------------------

Input 5

5

------------------------------------------

Input

-----------
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.in.read() does not read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307355/system-in-read-does-not-read)

Answer (score 1):

[System.in.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) reads the next byte of data from the input stream.

So, when you *enter* the second input in method.Exception(), there are actually two characters (three if you're using Windows) in the input stream. The second character (possibly the newline character) is read by the third (last) read() and the program ends.

Try the overloaded version of read() method: read(byte[] b) which 
*reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b*

Comment: *"So, when you enter the second character"* I guess you mean "the first character", because OP doesn't has a chance to enter a second one. I also assume that there a *three* characters in the stream, because OP probably uses Windows.

Comment: Ah yes, the second input after the `BufferedReader` one. I meant the first one of these `System.in.read()` versions :D.

Comment: Misunderstandings like these make me realize the enormity of the task of Natural Language Understanding and other challenges in AI. 
Anyway, made it more explicit now :)